# No Computer Allowed (Beware the Eater)

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, no-computers

*The answer is a relevant single word. No computer or digital calculator allowed. Beware the eater of red herring, if you happen to spot it.*

> 6 - 5 + 4 + 7 = ?
> 7 + 8 + 8 - (7-5) - (7-1) = ?
> 6 - 5 + 7 + 4 = ?
> 6 - 2 + 0 - 1 = ?
> 7 + 0 - 7 + 1 = ?
> 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Trying to avoid herrings and computers I'm going with

> Abacus

The logic behind it

> Write the numbers like on a digital calculator or clock and 'erase' the lines, that were subtracted.

> [image: solution]
>  6 gives us the red lines, the yellow ones for 5 get erased. 4 adds the green ones and 7 the last line on the top. Looks like an 8 without the bottom or like an A.
>  Doing so for all lines spells Abacus.

Comment: Great work dodging the cat!

Comment: It was hard, I love cats! (Thanks for editing, just noticed my spoilers were as lousy as my paint skills...)

Answer (score 5):

Answer is

> LOL

How to find

> The answers yield 12, 15, 12, 3, 1, 20. When converted to alphabet is gives us `LOLCAT`
>  Cats eat herrings.
>  Since red herrings are things that are not supposed to help. We can assume the word cat dos not belong.

Note I used the comment from @someoneinexistence.

Comment: Alas, you've been eaten by the eater of red herring. Try a completely different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is

> LOLCAT

How to find

> Results of equations are 12, 15, 12, 3, 1, 20, which are the alphabetical order of each letter of the solution. No computer used!

Comment: Cats eat fish, so this may be the red herring. I don't know though, sounds good to me.

Comment: Alas, you've been eaten by the eater of red herring. Try a completely different approach.

Comment: I must admit I was a bit puzzled by the "red herring" (meaning wrong problem/wrong solution) ;)  Well done for making a problem with 2 solutions!